# Re-direct homepage according to zip code input

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I am trying to create a page where the websites will ask the user to input their zip code. Once the user inputs their zip code website should redirect them to their zip codes homepage. Now I have 10 different zip codes that the user can input. So I created a function for ONE zip code, but now I am stuck, I am not sure if there is a way to input all zip codes in one function or should I create one function per zip code. Thank you for your help.

```
     <script>
    function ver(){

    var eje=document.getElementById('zip_code').value;
    var che=document.getElementById('lugar').value;

    var cheje = che.toLowerCase();

    if( (eje == 11385 )||(cheje=="ridgewood" ) || (cheje=="glendale") || (cheje=="flushing")){
    window.location.assign("c:/users/lui/desktop/fluidimaging.html")
    }    

    else{ alert("you did not enter a city or a zip code"); }
    }




    </script>


    <HTML> 




    <form>      

    <legend>Please Enter Your City or Zip Code</legend>           <label for ="shippingName">City: 
    </label>          <input type = "text" name = "Name" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" id="lugar" <br/>


      <label for = "billingzip">Zip code:</label>         <input type = "text" name = "zip" id = 
     "zip_code" pattern = "[0-9]{5}"  required><br/> </form>

      <input type = "submit" onclick="ver()" class="submit" value = "Verify"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would like to suggest that you the following solution.

```
var zipCodeApps = { 
   90507: 'https://app.ca.com',
   90890: 'https://app.ny.com'
}
```

This can be obtained from a REST API call to your application's backend service.
The next step would be to get the user's preferred/ location zip code

```
 var eje=document.getElementById('zip_code').value
```

now you can do a lookup in the above object model like

```
var zipCodeBasedAppUrl = zipCodeApps[eje];
if(undefined !== zipCodeBasedAppUrl) window.location.href = zipCodeBasedAppUrl;
```

This way your code looks nice, if you want to get the zip code specific URL for an input from the REST API, that would also be a good option considering the level of security and the sensitivity of the data your application has, choose the right approach.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
function ver() {

    var eje = document.getElementById('zip_code').value;
    var che = document.getElementById('lugar').value;

    var cheje = che.toLowerCase();

    if (eje == 11385) {
        window.location.assign("c:/users/lui/desktop/fluidimaging.html");
    } else if(eje == 11386) {
        window.location.assign("c:/users/lui/desktop/xyz.html");
    } else {
        alert("you did not enter a city or a zip code");
    }
}
```